# Unusual JS end result via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my user-facing page I have this section:

```
  <div class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
     <ul style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <li><a id="tab_1" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Section 1</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab_2" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Section 2</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab_3" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Section 3</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab_4" href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Section 4</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab_5" href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Section 5</strong></a></li>
      <li><a id="tab_6" href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Submit</strong></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

The PHP that the AJAX call is coming from looks like this:

```
if($secErr1 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['tab_1'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Section 1</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_1'] = "<strong>Section 1</strong>";
}

if($secErr2 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['tab_2'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Section 2</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_2'] = "<strong>Section 2</strong>";
}

if($secErr3 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['tab_3'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Section 3</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_3'] = "<strong>Section 3</strong>";
}

if($secErr4 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['tab_4'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Section 4</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_4'] = "<strong>Section 4</strong>";
}

if($secErr5 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['errorText_doSave5'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">Section(s) of this page appear to be incomplete</span>";
    $report_checkReport['checkReport'] .= "<strong>Section 5</strong> is missing information<br>";
    $report_checkReport['tab_5'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Section 5</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_5'] = "<strong>Section 5</strong>";
}

if($secErr6 === "1") {
    $report_checkReport['tab_6'] = "<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><strong>Submit</strong></span>";
} else {
    $report_checkReport['tab_6'] = "<strong>Submit</strong>";
}

echo json_encode($report_checkReport);
```

There is also a lot more going on in the PHP call, as it is checking an entire multi paged form and will (once I've solved this issue) either display a submit button or error messages. When the "Check" button is pressed and the AJAX call returns a result, if something is wrong on one of the tabs I'm simply trying to get the tab to go from normal to red text. Fairly simple and logical, right?

But, when I do this process, Firebug tells me that precisely the correct expected result is returned back from the PHP (yay!) however the end result displayed on the page becomes messed up (boo). The menu which was previously (as illustrated in the first section of code) changes from being:

```
Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3 | Section 4 | Section 5 | Submit
```

To become:

```
Section 2 | Section 3 | Section 4 | Section 5 | Section 5 | Submit
```

Of course the links are all still pointing to the right places but the text is quite messed up. Section 1 seems to echo Section 2 now etc as shown. Firebug reports it is not soming from the AJAX at all - check this coming from the Firebug log, refer to the end of the log for data specific to the problem.

POST post.7.VisFelAp.php?appID=1&ident=checkReport

200 OK

callisto

415 B

192.168.30.128:80

9ms
ParamsHeadersPostResponseHTMLJSONCacheCookies

```
{"resultImg_hostOrganisation":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_postalAddress":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_streetAddress":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_organisationPhone":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_contactPerson":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_positionHeld":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_phoneDDI":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_email":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_wwPersonName":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_wwPositionHeld":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_visitingFellow":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_propDate1From":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_propDate1To":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_propDate2From":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_propDate2To":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_themeAndPurpose":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_activsAndOutcomes":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_benefitToNZPriSec":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_fitAGsStraObj":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_support":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","resultImg_dessemination":"<img src=\".\/gfx\/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">","errorText_doSave4":"<span style=\"color: #2dac4e;\">Data appears ok here<\/span>","tab_1":"<strong>Section 1<\/strong>","tab_2":"<strong>Section 2<\/strong>","tab_3":"<strong>Section 3<\/strong>","tab_4":"<strong>Section 4<\/strong>","tab_5":"<strong>Section 5<\/strong>","tab_6":"<strong>Submit<\/strong>"}
```

1 request

415 B

9ms (onload: 1.93s)

So why is the tabs text data being echoed in the wrong places on the user facing page once this check has been initiated? Is it some weird simple little JS quirk I can fix somehow?

Update - as told more code was needed. There is a .js file in the page head, the section of which that handled the AJAX looks like this:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    // <...snip cos you don't want the long list of functioning items...>
    $("#checkReport").click(checkReport);
})
```

and

```
function checkReport() {
$.post('./post.7.VisFelAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=checkReport', $('#checkReport').serialize(), function(data) {
    // Tab 1
    $("#errorText_hostOrganisation").html(data.errorText_hostOrganisation);
    $("#resultImg_hostOrganisation").html(data.resultImg_hostOrganisation);
    $("#errorText_postalAddress").html(data.errorText_postalAddress);
    $("#resultImg_postalAddress").html(data.resultImg_postalAddress);
    $("#errorText_streetAddress").html(data.errorText_streetAddress);
    $("#resultImg_streetAddress").html(data.resultImg_streetAddress);
    $("#errorText_organisationPhone").html(data.errorText_organisationPhone);
    $("#resultImg_organisationPhone").html(data.resultImg_organisationPhone);
    $("#errorText_contactPerson").html(data.errorText_contactPerson);
    $("#resultImg_contactPerson").html(data.resultImg_contactPerson);
    $("#errorText_positionHeld").html(data.errorText_positionHeld);
    $("#resultImg_positionHeld").html(data.resultImg_positionHeld);
    $("#errorText_phoneDDI").html(data.errorText_phoneDDI);
    $("#resultImg_phoneDDI").html(data.resultImg_phoneDDI);
    $("#errorText_email").html(data.errorText_email);
    $("#resultImg_email").html(data.resultImg_email);
    $("#tab_1").html(data.tab_1);
    // Tab 2
    $("#errorText_wwPersonName").html(data.errorText_wwPersonName);
    $("#resultImg_wwPersonName").html(data.resultImg_wwPersonName);
    $("#errorText_wwPositionHeld").html(data.errorText_wwPositionHeld);
    $("#resultImg_wwPositionHeld").html(data.resultImg_wwPositionHeld);
    $("#errorText_visitingFellow").html(data.errorText_visitingFellow);
    $("#resultImg_visitingFellow").html(data.resultImg_visitingFellow);
    $("#errorText_propDate1From").html(data.errorText_propDate1From);
    $("#resultImg_propDate1From").html(data.resultImg_propDate1From);
    $("#errorText_propDate1To").html(data.errorText_propDate1To);
    $("#resultImg_propDate1To").html(data.resultImg_propDate1To);
    $("#errorText_propDate2From").html(data.errorText_propDate2From);
    $("#resultImg_propDate2From").html(data.resultImg_propDate2From);
    $("#errorText_propDate2To").html(data.errorText_propDate2To);
    $("#resultImg_propDate2To").html(data.resultImg_propDate2To);
    $("#errorText_propDate3From").html(data.errorText_propDate3From);
    $("#resultImg_propDate3From").html(data.resultImg_propDate3From);
    $("#errorText_propDate3To").html(data.errorText_propDate3To);
    $("#resultImg_propDate3To").html(data.resultImg_propDate3To);
    $("#tab_1").html(data.tab_2);
    // Tab 3
    $("#errorText_themeAndPurpose").html(data.errorText_themeAndPurpose);
    $("#resultImg_themeAndPurpose").html(data.resultImg_themeAndPurpose);
    $("#errorText_activsAndOutcomes").html(data.errorText_activsAndOutcomes);
    $("#resultImg_activsAndOutcomes").html(data.resultImg_activsAndOutcomes);
    $("#errorText_benefitToNZPriSec").html(data.errorText_benefitToNZPriSec);
    $("#resultImg_benefitToNZPriSec").html(data.resultImg_benefitToNZPriSec);
    $("#errorText_fitAGsStraObj").html(data.errorText_fitAGsStraObj);
    $("#resultImg_fitAGsStraObj").html(data.resultImg_fitAGsStraObj);
    $("#errorText_support").html(data.errorText_support);
    $("#resultImg_support").html(data.resultImg_support);
    $("#errorText_dessemination").html(data.errorText_dessemination);
    $("#resultImg_dessemination").html(data.resultImg_dessemination);
    $("#tab_2").html(data.tab_3);
    // Tab 4
    $("#errorText_doSave4").html(data.errorText_doSave4);
    $("#resultImg_doSave4").html(data.resultImg_doSave4);
    $("#tab_3").html(data.tab_4);
    // Tab 5
    $("#errorText_doSave5").html(data.errorText_doSave5);
    $("#resultImg_doSave5").html(data.resultImg_doSave5);
    $("#tab_4").html(data.tab_5);
    // Tab 6
    $("#errorText_sub_1").html(data.errorText_sub_1);
    $("#resultImg_sub_1").html(data.resultImg_sub_1);
    $("#checkReport").html(data.checkReport);
    $("#tab_6").html(data.tab_6);
}, 'json' );
}
```

I did also neglect to mention that I am using jQuery on this page. Hope this is enough?

Comment: Without seeing the code that actually handles the Ajax result, and displays the menu, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Paul - question updated displaying more code now.

Comment: This is the worst mix or HTML, PHP, JSON, Javascript, ...  I think you should try to return all your data in a better structured manner, not a full-on HTML to decode. Just check data, return arrays, and then use JS to change your page. Sorry this is too much to debug. You need to rethink the structure and then do some looping as this is to... predefined.

Comment: @Cassandra - This seems okay to me: `$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_1);`, but the others seem a bit fishy: `$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_2);`, `$("#tab_2").html(data.tab_3);` etc, etc.

Comment: @somethinghere You could be right about what you are saying however it's not exactly helpful to the problem in hand. If you can offer an example of how to achieve this in a better and simpler way (the overall picture) I'm more than happy to look at it!

Comment: Can you display your php reply/json again, you had it in the question but it would appear you have now removed it.

Comment: @NewToJS Hi New, nothing was removed however the reply was edited by JAAulde into a code format as opposed to a text format. It's still there, in one long thin line, but if it helps I've also placed it in a pastebin for you: http://pastebin.com/5aJMn7Py

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem but this should help you slim down the source code. **If** the object names/key all match the element id's this should work just fine for you rather than having to ` $("#errorText_hostOrganisation").html(data.errorText_hostOrganisation);` you should be able to `[].forEach.call(Object.keys(data), function(key){ $("#"+key).html(data[key]);});` and this will loop through for you.

Comment: @NewToJS That has caught my interest, though I'm unclear (not experienced enough) to understand how to apply that and where. Wish there was a better way to communicate then just here about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs you're targeting in the code which inserts all that (the big block of JS at the end of your post) are `#tab_1`, `#tab_1` again, then `#tab_2`, `#tab_3`, `#tab_4`, (skipping `#tab_5`), and then `#tab_6`.

Fix those to be `#tab_1` - `#tab_6` and it should look the way you want.

**Your Code**

```
// Tab 1
// ...snip...
$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_1);
// Tab 2
// ...snip...
$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_2);
// Tab 3
// ...snip...
$("#tab_2").html(data.tab_3);
// Tab 4
// ...snip...
$("#tab_3").html(data.tab_4);
// Tab 5
// ...snip...
$("#tab_4").html(data.tab_5);
// Tab 6
// ...snip...
$("#tab_6").html(data.tab_6);
```

**Modified to be correct**

```
// Tab 1
// ...snip...
$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_1);
// Tab 2
// ...snip...
$("#tab_2").html(data.tab_2);
// Tab 3
// ...snip...
$("#tab_3").html(data.tab_3);
// Tab 4
// ...snip...
$("#tab_4").html(data.tab_4);
// Tab 5
// ...snip...
$("#tab_5").html(data.tab_5);
// Tab 6
// ...snip...
$("#tab_6").html(data.tab_6);
```

Comment: Such a simple error on my part and I could not find it. Thank you so very much! Paul got to it just a fraction first but clearly both answers are right and accepted.

Comment: As you long as you got it fixed, that's all that matters

Comment: Both answers come up with exactly the same time stamp on my screen... and both are correct... sometimes it would be nice to give out the green tick to more than one person.

Answer (score 1):

In your handler code, you say:

```
$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_1);
```

which is a good start, but in the `// Tab 2` section, we see:

```
$("#tab_1").html(data.tab_2);
```

and so on into the following tabs. Make sure you correct these to

```
$("#tab_2").html(data.tab_2);
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks Paul, it is very appreciated. This is my first time using AJAX so trying to get used to it. Seems I miss the obvious from time to time!